# codeigniter define default sessions automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When a user `logs in`, then his required `sessions` are generated...

```
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data_array);
```

however how can i do this for non logged in users so i can store some `sessions` in every page `efficiently`?

one way is to check if `session` `exists` and if not `generate` it in every `controller`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some research and since i finally didnt want it on all my pages to check for the non-logged in session, i simply checked if not exsits then create it on my required files.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do that in an overridden `MY_Controller` class:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if ( !$this->session->userdata('some_session_key')) // change this to one of your session data keys
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                // set guest session settings here
            ));
        }
    }
}
```